# convert url segment to get variable keeping others get variables

Tags: nginx, nginx-config

I can't fix that I have a url

**domain.com/api/class/access/1/index.php?username=usuariodemo&name=sala**

where **/1/ is a ID** so, I need convert /1/ to get variables like

**domain.com/api/class/access/index.php?id=1&username=usuariodemo&name=sala**

That is pure PHP not framework my index.php is located on folder api/class/access/index.php

I have this I try others but this explain me better waht I want do

```
location /api/class/access/(.*)/* {
       try_files $uri $uri/ /api/class/access/index.php?id=$1&$query_string;
}
```

That show me:

***No input file specified.***

Thanks!
Regards!

Answer (score 0):

The `location` statement in your question is invalid and probably unnecessary.

If you want to rewrite a URI ending with `.php` it may be easiest to place a `rewrite` statement inside the block that processes all `.php` URIs, usually: `location ~ \.php$ { ... }`.

For example:

```
location ~ \.php$ {
    rewrite ^(/api/class/access/)(\d+)/(index.php)$ $1$3?id=$2 last;
    ...
}
```